# Solving an ODE with exponentials

Tags: derivatives

$$e^{x^2y}\ \mathrm dx+ e^{y-x}\ \mathrm dy=0$$

I have been trying this for a long. I am not able to solve it. I have solved similar questions, but I have failed to solve this specifically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?